# Should you use は or が when you have a compound subject?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-は, particle-と, particle-が

What do you put in as the subject marker if there is more than one subject? For example

> Adam と Sarah ___ すしがすきです.

Answer (score 1):

The particle will be the same regardless of number, so you would use は. Whether it's one person or two hundred people who like sushi, the particle will not change.

> AdamとSarah**は**すしがすきです。

Comment: Unless it's everyone. 「みんな**が**すしが好きです。」「誰も**が**すしが好きです。」 (Note: You can say 「みんな**は**すしが好きです。」, but then みんな refers to an entire **group** of people (in the sense of "they all" or "we all") not **all** people.)

Comment: 「みんな、すしが好きです。」とも言いますよね・・・。どうして「みんな」には「は」・「が」がついてなくてもいいんでしょうね。。。？

Comment: 「（人は）みんなすしが好きです。」のように副詞的な用法になっているからですかね？

Answer (score 1):

Just the same as if there was only one person:

> AdamとSarahはすしが好{す}きです。

The topic of the conversation, marked by は, is the pair of both Adam and Sarah. Topics can be very complex phrases; they don't have to be just single words.